# Fetching data from database through dropdown into the table | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropdown

Hello I am new to laravel
I have a problem while getting data from a database via dropdown. I have a dropdown for classes so when the user selects any class and click the submit button then the students related to that class will be displayed below in the table... I have a table in the database for students where the student class id exists for every student. I can't really understand the logic for this problem.
Anyone can help me?

//My controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $classes = StudentsClass::pluck('class_name', 'id')->all();
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('admin.students.attendance.index', compact('classes', 'students'));
    }

    public function mytableAjax($id)

    {

        $students = DB::table("students")

            ->where("student_id",$id)

            ->lists("class_name","id");

        return json_encode($students);

    }
```

//My view

```
        <option value="">--- Select State ---</option>

        @foreach ($classes as $key => $value)

            <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>

        @endforeach

    </select>

    <table id="studentsData" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list-search">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Attendance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            @foreach($students as $student)
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>{{$student->id}}</th>
                <td>{{$student->student_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$student->first_name}} {{$student->last_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="gender">
                            <option>Present</option>
                            <option>Absent</option>
                            <option>Leave</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            @endforeach
    </table>
    <a class="fas fa-folder-open btn btn-success float-right mb-4 mr-2"> Save</a>
</div>
```

//ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('select[name="students_class_id"]').on('change', function() {

            var classID = $(this).val();

            if(classID) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: '/myform/ajax/'+classID,

                    type: "GET",

                    dataType: "json",


                    success:function(data) {




                        $('table[id="studentsData"]').empty();

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                            $('table[id="studentsData"]').append('<td   value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</td  >');

                        });


                    }

                });

            }

            // else{
            //
            //     $('table[id="studentsData"]').empty();
            //
            // }

        });

    });
```

This is what i tried

Comment: You need to set up ajax and get related students based on your dropdown. You need to show us what you tried so that we can guide you

Comment: Ok i try something else in the ajax Below is the code...

Comment: Pls read the above edited question

Comment: Can you try `dd($students)` and check in your Network tab in browser? Is it returning the right data?

Comment: Without dd($students) it give me the 200 ok page and with ($students) now it returning nothing

Comment: Sir i think my problem is in the ajax code... I cannot really get that logic ....

Comment: Check that key value part in ajax code

Comment: you get 200 but do you get your desired data? In Network > Response, you should be able to see the returned data from backend

Comment: No i am not getting the desired data. What can I do ?

Comment: `$students = DB::table("students")

            ->where("student_id",$id)

            ->lists("class_name","id");` probably this part is wrong. Can you try `Student::get()` to test?

Comment: yup i try Student::get(); instead of that but same result

Comment: `return response()->json('students', $students);`, but before that make sure you're getting into that mytableAjax method with `dd($id)` at the top

Comment: I am getting the same result after applying that but let me show you my route too

Comment: Route::get('students/attendance/index',array('as'=>'myform','uses'=>'AttendanceController@mytableAjax'));
Route::get('myform/ajax/{id}',array('as'=>'myform.ajax','uses'=>'AttendanceController@index'));

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong.

```
public function mytableAjax($id)
{
    $students = Student::where('class_id', $id)->get();
    // if you try dd($students), you should see it in Network > Preview

    return response()->json(['students => $students]);
}
```

And then,

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/myform/ajax/'+classID,
   type: "GET",
   success:function(data) {
      console.log(data.students)
   }
})
```

Comment: No I am getting the same result sir